# How to know the port at which a gRPC request was received

Tags: c++, grpc, grpc-c++

I have a c++ gRPC service which listens on multiple ports, `55555`, `44444` and `44888`, with the following RPC:

```
message FooRequest { string message = 1; }
message FooResponse { string message = 1; }
service FooService {
  rpc FooRpc(FooRequest) returns (FooResponse) {}
}
```

I add multiple ports for listening by calling the API `grpc::ServerBuilder::AddListeningPort(...)`

So clients of my service can invoke the RPC at any of these ports. I want to know on the service side, at which port the RPC was received, is it possible?

```
Status FooRpc(ServerContext* context, const FooRequest* request,
              FooResponse* response) override {
 // how to know the port at which this RPC was received?
 return Status::OK;
}
```

I want to use different types of authentication on RPCs received on different ports. Port 55555 is exposed only within the device, (inter process communication) so requests received on it don't need authentication. Port 44888 is exposed to the internet and so we want certificate based authentication for requests received on it.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is this because you have "admin/advanced" API and/or functionalities that is only available via a non-exposed port? If that's the case, there's a better pattern you can use, and I can write an answer around that.

Comment: @Frank yes sort of. We want to use different types of authentication on requests received on different ports. For example the port 55555 is exposed only within the device, (inter process comm) so request received on this port don't need authentication. The port 44888 is exposed on the internet and we want certificate based authentication for the requests received on it.

Comment: now I'm confused. Auth-related stuff is configured through the second argument to `grpc::ServerBuilder::AddListeningPort()`. It's already a per-port feature. Is there specific you are trying to do that can't be accomplished via `SslServerCredentials` and/or `AuthMetadataProcessor`?

Comment: The 2 way authentication works via `SslServerCredentials`, however for one-way authentication (with `SslServerCredentialsOptions::force_client_auth = false`) we want to to `use/password` based authentication, for which we need to know which port the request arrived at. I have not looked at `AuthMetadataProcessor`, will explore. Will be grateful if you have any pointers! Thanks!